# Javascript in VisualStudio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-power-tools

Are there any good, reliable plugins for Visual Studio that make Javascript development less painful?

Every time I write a closing brace or a semicolon VS feels the need to inappropriately and incorrectly re-indent nearby code.

Comment: Best thing I did was just turn off auto-formatting - I was never able to get it to work with how I format my brackets.

Comment: @Jason indeed - shutting off formatting altogether for JS is the best option.  Not sure why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking under Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> JScript?

There are lots of settings you can change there to tell VS to indent or not indent code.

Answer (score 0):

[JetBrains ReSharper 6](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/05/resharper-6-enhances-the-javascript-experience/) supports JavaScript quite good. Unfortunately it is quite slow.